# what is the best practice for converting nested loops to streams, if the nested loops are over different data types?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have found examples of converting nested loops to streams if the data types are the same, but what i would like is to combine lists of two different data types into all possible combinations and do something with each combination.

I can do this using nested .forEach() sections in my stream pipeline, but i just see so many suggestions that it is better to avoid forEach as much as you can.  For instance I'm not sure if nesting forEachs will break the ability to benefit from parallel streams if the lists were big data instead of a couple enum values.   Is there a better best practice to implement the following example function:  allCombosUsingStreams() ?  Thank you :)

```
    static enum Color { RED, YELLOW, GREEN };
    static enum Sound { PIANO, BIRD };
    
    void doSomething( Color c, Sound s ) { System.out.println( c + ", " + s ); }
    
    void allCombosUsingLoops()
    {
        for( Color color : Color.values() )
            for( Sound sound : Sound.values() )
                doSomething( color, sound );
    }   
    
    void allCombosUsingStreams()
    {
        Stream.of( Color.values())
            .forEach( color -> Stream.of( Sound.values() )
                    .forEach( sound -> doSomething( color, sound ) ) );             
    }
```

I tried the above implementation and it works.  I'm not stuck.  I just want to know from experts if this is considered a good way of handling this situation using streams.  Or even if this is a case where there isn't any benefit to the stream approach.

Comment: "*...i just see so many suggestions that it is better to avoid forEach as much as you can.*" - This statement - as-is - is nonsense. There may be an argument for `for`-loops over `forEach`-loops to improve performance, but this is just a guess and I would always profile before making such a statement. Using `forEach` is absolutely fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But what's the point? The `for` loop is just as clear and concise.

Comment: I find the for-loops much easier to read.  The only possible benefit of Streams would be parallel streams, but that requires taking care to write thread-safe code.

Comment: Using forEach is usually an indication you shouldn't be bothering with streams in the first place.  Using fors is good strictly on the basis of readability, not least because you can freely modify other variables.

Answer (score 1):

I might not be right; thinking aloud, how about using a [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) in the place of `forEach()` ?!!

```
void allCombosUsingStreams () {
        Stream.of(Color.values())
                .flatMap(color -> Stream.of(Sound.values())
                .map(sound -> new Object[]{color, sound}))
                .forEach(iteratorArray -> doSomething((Color) iteratorArray[0], (Sound) iteratorArray[1]));
    }
```

This code is an attempt to flatten the nested Stream of Sound values into a single stream (Object arrays containing Color and Sound pairs), thus reducing the usage of `forEach()`

This approach might better combine Color and Sound, partially aligned with the [functional programming paradigm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-programming-paradigm/).

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is not typical of stream usage.  Let's say I want to put each combo in a new `record` (immutable class). I could do it like this.

```
record Both(Color c, Sound s) {}
List<Both> list = allCombosUsingStreams();
list.foreEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Both[c=RED, s=PIANO]
Both[c=RED, s=BIRD]
Both[c=YELLOW, s=PIANO]
Both[c=YELLOW, s=BIRD]
Both[c=GREEN, s=PIANO]
Both[c=GREEN, s=BIRD]
```

- first stream the Color values (you could also use `Arrays.stream()`)
- then `flapMap` to flatten out the Sound values.
- since both `color` and `sound` are within the same scope, use them to create an instance of `Both`.
- and collect into a list.

```
List<Both> allCombosUsingStreams() {
        return Stream.of(Color.values()).flatMap(color -> Arrays
                .stream(Sound.values()).map(sound -> new Both(color, sound)))
                .toList();
```

If you used loops, you would first need to create an instance of a `List` to hold the values.  With streams, the list is created "under the hood" and returned after being populated.

However, the purpose of streams is to make it easier by using a `declarative way` of writing code.  It is not the end-all of doing things.  `Imperative ways` of using loops and other inherent features of the language as in your first example are fine.  And I have seen many who want to `"optimize"` their code by converting legacy code to streams.  This is a misnomer as streams incur quite a bit of overhead so upgrading legacy code for this reason is, imo, flawed.  Use whatever suits the situation.  Sometimes, a hybrid solution is best such as using the new `compute*` features in the `map` class in combination with  `for` loops.